# Extending IdentityUser with nullable foreign key to another IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm working on a framework which builds on .net core Identity. Let's say I wanted to extend the [`IdentityUser<TKey>`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/IdentityUser.cs#L42) class with a `ParentUserId` property while the developer should still be able to decide which type to use for the `TKey` primary key. This property would be a foreign key to another user, but could be `null` if the user doesn't have a parent.

Using `string` for `TKey` would work without problems because strings are nullable and don't conflict with the `where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>` constraint (although I don't know why). But if the developer decides to use `int`, I'm screwed.

Currently I'm thinking about a solution like this:

```
public class FrameworkUser<TKey, TNullableKey> : IdentityUser<TKey> 
       where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    public virtual TNullableKey ParentUserId { get; set; }

    // navigation property depending on ParentUserId
    public virtual FrameworkUser<TKey, TNullableKey> ParentUser { get; set; }
}
```

But I'm very unsure and don't think it's beautiful.

1. The developer could do something like `new FrameworkUser<string, int?>()` by mistake ([could be catched at runtime](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/221013/201551)). Would be great if something like `where TNullableKey : Nullable<TKey>` were possible.
2. I can't constraint `TNullableKey`. **`IEquatable`** doesn't allow nullable value types (i.e. `int?`), although I don't know if this will result in worse performance when used as a foreign key anyway. **`struct`** won't allow strings.
3. Getting the value of `ParentUserId` will differ depending on the type. For instance to securely get the value of an `int?`, I would check for `int?.HasValue` to be `true` and then get it's value from `int?.Value`. The same procedure is quite different for a `string` which could be `null`, empty, or have some chars. This would make switches from one type to another without extra work difficult/impossible.

Another solution could be having two implementations, one for `string` and one for `struct`, but that's not feasible because then I would also need to have two `IdentityStore<TUser>`s and so on.

So, what would you do?